# Prometheus merge lables

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have the following Prometheus query

```
label_replace(namespace_pod_name_container_name:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate{namespace="$namespace",container_name!=""}, "container", "$1", "container_name", "(.*)")
```

This will create a label `container` in which the values are the values of the label container_name.

| container_name | container | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| containerA | containerA | 0.5 |
| containerA | containerA | 0.6 |

How can I modify the above query in order to have an additional label composed by 2 labels: `pod_name-container_name`

Something like

| container_name | pod_name | new_label | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| containerA | podA | podA-containerA | 0.5 |
| containerA | podB | podB-containerA | 0.6 |

Comment: May I ask what is the motivation behind this question is?

Comment: @JensBaitinger it is to create a graph with the cpu usage by "new_label". If use "conainer_name" then I will have duplicated names and I will not be able to properly identify the container (e.g in which pod that container is running). If I use "pod_name" then I will not see the containers deployed inside the pods

Comment: What about making a graph like `aggregation by (pod_name, container_name) (someMetric)` or `someMetric{container_name="containerA"}` if you are only interested in one container